# data-table to card callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a DataTable in Dash where i would like to select a table row and have card component contents update off of that selection. I cannot figure out the proper callback for this. Here is some of the code.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
               'animal': ['falcon','dog','spider','fish'],
               'super_hero': ['Falcon', 'Scooby-Doo', 'Spider-Man', 'Aquaman'],
               'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
               'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
               'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
              )

 app.layout = dbc.Container([
  dbc.Row([
   dbc.Col([

dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns],
            data=df2.to_dict('records'),
            editable=False,
            filter_action="native",     
            sort_action="native",      
            sort_mode="multi",         
            column_selectable="single",  
            row_selectable="single",     
            row_deletable=False,         
            selected_columns=[],        
            selected_rows=[],           
            page_action="native",       
            page_current=0,             
            page_size=15,        
)      
]),
]),

dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(dbc.Card([ 
        dbc.CardBody([
            html.H4("Card title", className="card-title", id="card_num1"),
            html.P("Current Population", className="card-text",id="card_text1")
        ]),
        
    ])),
    dbc.Col(dbc.Card(card_content, color="secondary", inverse=True)),
    dbc.Col(dbc.Card(card_content, color="info", inverse=True)),
    
],  className="mb-4",), 

])

@app.callback([
Output('card_num1','children'),],
Input('table','value')

)

def update_card(slct_rows_names):
print('***************************************************************************')
print(slct_rows_names)
print("Names of selected rows if part of table after filtering: {}".format(slct_rows_names))
```

Ideally, after a row is selected. I would like each card to display column text. For example, if the row with spider was selected, the first card text would get updated to the value of animal ('spider'). The next card text would get updated to the value of super_hero('Spider-Man'). The last card text would display the value of num_legs(8)

Right now I can't get any value to print.

Answer (score 1):

`value` is not a valid property of `DataTable`. You could use [`active_cell`](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference) instead:

> active_cell (dict; optional): The row and column indices and IDs of the currently active cell. row_id is only returned if the data rows have an id key.

> active_cell is a dict with keys:
>
> - column (number; optional)
> - column_id (string; optional)
> - row (number; optional)
> - row_id (string | number; optional)

So what you could do here is use the `column_id` and `row` of the active cell to retrieve a value from your dataframe corresponding to the active column id and row:

```
@app.callback(Output("card_num1", "children"), Input("table", "active_cell"))
def update_card(slct_rows_names):
    if slct_rows_names:
        col = df2[slct_rows_names["column_id"]]
        val = col[slct_rows_names["row"]]
        return val
    return card_content # default value if no active cell
```

Complete example:

```
from dash import Dash
import pandas as pd
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

card_content = "default card content"

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "animal": ["falcon", "dog", "spider", "fish"],
        "super_hero": ["Falcon", "Scooby-Doo", "Spider-Man", "Aquaman"],
        "num_legs": [2, 4, 8, 0],
        "num_wings": [2, 0, 0, 0],
        "num_specimen_seen": [10, 2, 1, 8],
    },
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        dash_table.DataTable(
                            id="table",
                            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns],
                            data=df2.to_dict("records"),
                            editable=False,
                            filter_action="native",
                            sort_action="native",
                            sort_mode="multi",
                            column_selectable="single",
                            row_selectable="single",
                            row_deletable=False,
                            selected_columns=[],
                            selected_rows=[],
                            page_action="native",
                            page_current=0,
                            page_size=15,
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    dbc.Card(
                        dbc.CardBody(
                            [
                                html.H4(
                                    "Card title", className="card-title", id="card_num1"
                                ),
                                html.P(
                                    "Current Population",
                                    className="card-text",
                                    id="card_text1",
                                ),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                ),
                dbc.Col(dbc.Card(card_content, color="secondary", inverse=True)),
                dbc.Col(dbc.Card(card_content, color="info", inverse=True)),
            ],
            className="mb-4",
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("card_num1", "children"), Input("table", "active_cell"))
def update_card(slct_rows_names):
    if slct_rows_names:
        col = df2[slct_rows_names["column_id"]]
        val = col[slct_rows_names["row"]]
        return val
    return card_content


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```